# Facebook in Bada

Tags: social-networking, bada

How to create a facebook application in Bada? Which API should be refered? Please help me..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use the Osp::Social::Services namespace and you can find it here:
[link](http://static.bada.com/contents/docs/resources_1.2.0/com.osp.apireference.help/FramesetMain.html?menu=MC01010904&mtb1=&mtb2=)